# How to find all possible order with array item

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

Here is an array.

```
$item = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

I want to list all possible orders in this array like:

A
A,B
A,B,C
A,B,C,D
A,C
A,C,D
A,C,B
...
B,A
B,A,C
....

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this homework, if so please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: I think you should try yourself... try googling recursivity and permutation

Comment: There is nothing special about `php` in this problem. Its a general algorithm. You just need to know the algorithm. You can say "in php" IMO if you show us what codes you have written till now.

Comment: First result on Google: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/getting-all-permutations-array-php-74.html

Comment: I dont understand why this question has up votes....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) you want to know can be accomplished through [this algorithm](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml) and applying in a loop for the subsets.

> Initialize the first permutation with <1 <2 ...
>
> while there exists a mobile integer
>
> find the largest mobile integer k
>
> swap k and the adjacent integer it is looking at
>
> reverse the direction of all integers larger than k

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can use this recursive function:

```
function recursive_permutations($items,$perms = array( ))
{
 static $list;
 if (empty($items)) {
  $list[] = join(',', $perms);
 } else {
  for ($i = count($items)-1;$i>=0;--$i) {
   $newitems = $items;
   $newperms = $perms;
   list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
   array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
   recursive_permutations($newitems, $newperms);
  };
  return $list;
 };
}
$perms = recursive_permutations(array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($perms, true) . '</pre>';
```