# Calculating occurrences of the word in the text

Tags: php, regex, algorithm

I have a text in which I would like to calculate occurences of the phrase "lorem ipsum dolor".

> **Lorem ipsum dolor** sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. **Ipsum lorem dolor** Curabitur ac risus nunc. **Dolor ipsum lorem**.

The algorithm should be counting occurrences even if the searching phrase **is written in different order**. I've highlighted expected results. Is there any better way to achieve that than using regular expression with every possible combination?

In this case the result should be equal to 3

- Lorem ipsum dolor
- Ipsum lorem dolor
- Dolor ipsum lorem

The phrase will have about 3-4 words and string will be a content of web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$haystack = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ipsum lorem dolor Curabitur ac risus nunc. Dolor ipsum lorem.';
$needle = 'Lorem ipsum dolor';

$hayWords = str_word_count(
    strtolower($haystack), 
    1
);
$needleWords = str_word_count(
    strtolower($needle), 
    1
);
$needleWordsCount = count($needleWords);

$foundWords = array_intersect(
    $hayWords, 
    $needleWords
);

$count = array_reduce(
    array_keys($foundWords),
    function($counter, $item) use ($foundWords, $needleWordsCount) {
        for($i = $item; $i < $item + $needleWordsCount; ++$i) {
            if (!isset($foundWords[$i]))
                return $counter;
        }
        return ++$counter;
    },
    0
);

var_dump($count);
```

Comment: Works great until you get lorem ipsum dolor dolor - but then we are just getting silly! +1 this answer is as elegant as this is going to get

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: Mine works with lorem ipsum dolor dolor as well :)

Comment: This code will return a count of 4 with "lorem ipsum dolor dolor" which is technically wrong: it counts both the "lorem ipsum dolor" and the "ipsum dolor dolor", the latter of which isn't valid (although "lorem ipsum dolor lorem" would be correctly counted as 2)... but the likelihood of those combination are fairly slim

Answer (score 2):

You could try the regex:

```
/(?:(?:(?:lorem|ipsum|dolor)\s?)+)/gi
```

with `preg_match_all` and then count the number of matches. From your sample, you should get [3 matches](http://regex101.com/r/lR2lD6).

---

I'm not too good at algorithms nor at PHP, but an attempt...

```
<?php

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ipsum lorem dolor Curabitur ac risus nunc. Dolor ipsum lorem.';

$lower_string = strtolower($string);

$text = array('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor');

$perms = AllPermutations($text);
$result = 0;
foreach ($perms as $piece) {
    $phrase = join(' ', $piece);
    $result += substr_count($lower_string, $phrase);
}

# From http://stackoverflow.com/a/12749950/1578604
function AllPermutations($InArray, $InProcessedArray = array())
{
    $ReturnArray = array();
    foreach($InArray as $Key=>$value)
    {
        $CopyArray = $InProcessedArray;
        $CopyArray[$Key] = $value;
        $TempArray = array_diff_key($InArray, $CopyArray);
        if (count($TempArray) == 0)
        {
            $ReturnArray[] = $CopyArray;
        }
        else
        {
            $ReturnArray = array_merge($ReturnArray, AllPermutations($TempArray, $CopyArray));
        }
    }
    return $ReturnArray;
}

echo $result;
?>
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/TGplB9)

Comment: OP mentioned `Is there any better way to achieve that than using regular expression with every possible combination?`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Huh, seems I didn't pay enough attention. I find it strange that they tagged the question with regex though.

Comment: Look at my answer for a php build-in solution.

Comment: @Anyone Your answer is not a proper answer. It's a link-only answer.

Comment: It's pretty much all the OP needs, but I've updated it with examples (which only take a click). This was the first result I found on google btw.

Comment: I will update this, now that the OP has formulated the question better, this case yields the proper results. Not sure if it's faster than matching against all combinations, but sure is easier to write!

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Updated answer to include non-regex solution.

Comment: Guys, check out my answer with the memory consumption chart too.

Comment: @Jerry, +1 for the answer.

Comment: @AliGajani I don't get how that `getrusage` works exactly (my code gives the memory usage roughly [in between yours and Mark](http://ideone.com/dHkBJ8)), but if you time your function, I had to make [250 iterations](http://ideone.com/G717JK) (the IDE couldn't support taking 1000) and it gives an average of 0.00011 sec/run, while with my code, I can do [1000 iterations](http://ideone.com/OD3TPg) and it gives an average of 0.00005 sec/run (twice as fast as yours).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this: https://www.php.net/substr_count

```php
$text = 'This is a test';
echo strlen($text); // 14

echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2

// the string is reduced to 's is a test', so it prints 1
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3);

// the text is reduced to 's i', so it prints 0
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3, 3);

// generates a warning because 5+10 > 14
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 5, 10);


// prints only 1, because it doesn't count overlapped substrings
$text2 = 'gcdgcdgcd';
echo substr_count($text2, 'gcdgcd');
```

Comment: This will return only 1 result either. "The algorithm should be counting occurrences even if the searching phrase is written in different order."

Comment: Additionally you could put both the needle and haystack through strtolower (or upper if you please) and compare "case-insensitive"

Comment: @estshy, if I understand correctly you want to match the 3 words differently in a row?

Comment: @Anyone Please take a look at my question, I've added some information that may help you better undestand the problem.

Comment: Yes I see. In that case I would recommend Jerry's answer, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Note: Works with "Lorem ipsum dolor dolor" as well.

Good evening everyone. I have figured out another technique. This one uses a varying approach to what Mark Baker did, which I appreciate very much. Also, go down **to see memory usage**.

In a nutshell, it takes basic string (lorem ipsum dolor) that needs to be matched, which is then shuffled into all possible combinations (in this case 3! = 6).

Further,all those 6 combination of strings are then added into array which is used to do the matching substr_count. I am also using `shuffle()`, `in_array` and `array_push`.

The code is self explanatory and if you are curious, here's my [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/kwWW3T). This is Mark Baker's solution on [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/aFXqhE). They both take the same amount of time and memory, and my solution is 4 lines shorter, if not more elegant :)

```
<?php

    $string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ipsum lorem dolor Curabitur ac risus nunc. Dolor ipsum lorem.';

//convert main string to lowercase to have an even playing field
    $string2 = strtolower($string);
    $substring = 'lorem ipsum dolor';

//add the first lorem ipsum dolor to launch the array 
    $arr = array($substring);

//run until the array is full with all possible combinations i.e. 6 (factorial of 3)
    for ($i=0; $i<=20; $i++) {
        $wordArray = explode(" ",$substring);
        shuffle($wordArray);
        $randString= implode(" ",$wordArray);

//if random string isn't in the array, then only you push the new value 
        while (! (in_array($randString,$arr)) ) {
            array_push($arr,$randString);
        }

    }

//var_dump($arr);

//here, we do the matching, and this is pretty self explanatory
    $n = sizeof($arr);
    for ($q=0; $q<=$n; $q++) {
        $sum += substr_count($string2,$arr[$q]);
    }

    echo "Total occurances: ".$sum;

?>
```

### Memory Usage

As you can already see, Mark's code ups me on +2 occasions, but the difference is very negligible due to the nature of this programme, and the data complexity associated. Obviously, the difference could be big given the program's complexity, but this is what it is.

[image]

Comment: However, your code does give notices and warnings, and your line count approach is rather disingenuous

Comment: Yes, those are minor warnings which can be fixed. I just wanted to demonstrate that it could be done in an alternative way and I spent a considerable amount of time getting my head around to it, hence thought of sharing. Also, I am not counting lines?

Comment: Since when does less lines mean better?