# how does this php code works? (permutations)

Tags: php, permutation

I saw this function ([Get all permutations of a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222835/get-all-combinations-of-a-php-array)), but i can't understand on how some of these coding works, can help to explain? I am new in php by the way. 

 Here's the code:

```
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array()) 
    {
        if (empty($items))
        { 
            echo join(' ', $perms) . "<br />";
        } 
        else 
        {
            for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) 
            {
                 $newitems = $items;
                 $newperms = $perms;
                 list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
                 array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
                 pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
             }
        }
    }
    $arr = array('peter', 'paul', 'mary');
    pc_permute($arr);
```

why use`list($foo)`? I tried to use array, it doesn't work(I don't understand list)

 And why use `array_unshift($newperms, $foo);`? for what? Sorry, I really new in php T.T

Answer (score 0):

List takes an array and place it in variable ,if the array size is 3 for example then in the list function you need to mention 3 variables.

```
list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
```

What he have done is to take `$i` put it in `$foo` and remove it from the array.
This could also look like this -

```
$foo = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1)[0];
```

But some will consider this code as harder to read.

Then the `array_unshift($newperms, $foo)` means take `$foo` and place it at the start of `$newperms` array. so if the array looked like

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )
```

and `$foo` equals `d` the array after running the function would look like this -

```
Array ( [0] => d [1] => a [2] => b [3] => c )
```

Comment: so the variable `$foo` will only content 1 element each time? then why need to use list but not the normal variable? or can it modified to a simpler way?

Comment: because `array_splice` return an array and you need to convert it into string.