# Position array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with keys `1`, `2` and `3`.

I would like to rearrange elements in a circular manner. So it will be like this:

```
1 => parent
2 =>  child
3 =>  child

2 =>  parent
1 =>  child
3 =>  child

3 =>  parent
1 =>  child
2 =>  child
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I don't understand the sequence, `1 2 3` -> `2 1 3` -> `3 1 2`. Are you looking for all permutations or ...?

Comment: Exactly, but result limit only three possibility based on how may item in array, not six.

Comment: Okay there's still no consistency with that sequence. `{1,2,3} {1,3,2} {2,1,3} {2,3,1} {3,1,2} {3,2,1}` Is all of them, do you just want to stop after three items? You should explain what exactly you need this for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223120/4229270

Comment: Yes I want to stop after the three parent listed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question,

```
$parent = array('1','2','3');
foreach($parent as $key => $value) {
    echo $value ."\n";
    $p = $parent;
    unset($p[$key]);
    foreach($p as $k => $v) {
        echo '     ' . $v ."\n";
    }
}
```