# Text fragment permutation in PHP?

Tags: php, text, permutation

I am looking for a 'reasonably fast' PHP method to find all possible permutations of specific text fragments.

*Note, no need for array recursion, but an array could be big.*

Example:

```
<?php
    $fragments [] = "al";
    $fragments [] = "ex";
    $fragments [] = "00";

    $permutations = permuteTxt($fragments);
    print_r($permutations);
?>
```

Result:

- alex00
- 00alex
- exal00
- al00ex
- 00exal
- ex00al

I would appreciate your help, and a brief explanation of your brainstorming on how you got it together.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223120/2558648

Comment: Thank you guys, should I delete question or to correctly act now? Thanks

Comment: Thread closed, awaiting your votes.
I used the resource referred by @Servuc at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223120/2558648