# How to generate 3 digit possible number using provided numbers

Tags: php

Is there a php function to produce,
if I provide three number for example 123 and it should return numbers which contain exactly provided digits.

> eg1. provided no=123 and return 132,231,312,321,213
>
> eg2.provided no=122 and return 212,221

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222835/get-all-permutations-of-a-php-array

Comment: Oh I see it surely is same type :) thanks

Comment: Google is amazing, if you use it.. :o