# Random Word And change the layout with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, random, numbers, cpu-word

I have 3 words: (book, help, air)

I want these 3 words to be displayed in different modes

```
Example :
book help air
book air help
help air book
air book help
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Set your word as array

```
$array = ['book', 'help', 'air'];

echo random_string_from_array( $array, 10);


// Function For string from words array randomization 
   
// $array is array of words, $n is number of times of randomization of words
    function random_string_from_array( $array, $n)
    {

        $my_str = '';
        
        for( $i == 1; $i <= $n; $i++ )
        {
            
          shuffle($array);
          
          $my_str .= implode(" ",$array);
          $my_str .= "<br>";
          
        }
    
        return $my_str;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - Can something be put instead of 10 to indicate n (non-duplicate)?

Comment: you're welcome, if you want all of permutations your answer is here : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222835/get-all-permutations-of-a-php-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function: `array_rand` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
$array = ['book', 'help', 'air'];

echo array_rand($array);
```