# Generating all combinations of an array of search keywords without fixed size in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to generate an array of all combinations of an input array of search keywords, I have referred to a Javascript solution [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array), and I have to achieve the same kind of implementation in PHP, I have tried like below. I am not able to get the final output when I called. Thanks in advance

```
    function getCombinations($chars){
      $result = array();
      $f = function ($prefix, $chars, $result) use (&$f) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($chars); $i++) {
          $item = $prefix.' '. $chars[$i];
          array_push($result, $item);
          return $f($item, array_slice($chars, ($i + 1)), $result);
        }
      };

      $f('', $chars, $result);
      return $result;
    }
```

sample array

```
$chars = array("new", "world", "net", "cafe");
$result = getCombinations($chars);
```

**Expected output**

```
 [' new world net cafe', ' new world cafe', ' world net cafe', ' new world net', ' new net cafe', ' world cafe', ' new world', ' world net', ' new cafe', ' net cafe', ' new net', ' world', ' cafe', ' new', ' net']
```

**Update**
I don't see the expected answer like above from this suggested link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222835/get-all-permutations-of-a-php-array) by [bill-karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)