# Build a probability tree using php?

Tags: php, tree, probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)

I have an array that has a list of options,
Each option is unique and cannot be repeated.

I want to build a probability tree using these options:

```
$options = array('1','2','3','4','A','E','I','O');
```

So one valid line could be `1-2-E-3-O-I-4-A`

How can I do this? (or at least point me in the right direction!)

Comment: Actually you want find all permutations of the `$options` array?

Comment: Please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers). It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) { 
        print join('-', $perms) . "<br />";
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $newitems = $items;
            $newperms = $perms;
            list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
        }
    }
}

$options = array( '1','2','3','4','A','E','I','O' );
$mass = pc_permute( $options );

?>
```

Comment: I want to show all possible lines

Comment: @Hailwood something like this?

Comment: No, he want's ALL possible lines, not just one random...

Comment: Can the keys repeat? Meaning, can one of the options be `E-1-A-4-2-E-O-4`?

Comment: Like he said in the question, $options values are unique, so char E can be only one in the line.

Comment: This should do then. Thanx @fsehat.

Comment: Whilst I have accepted this answer as it does answer the question, it could be a good idea to cite the original source..

Comment: @Hailwood What exactly are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is probably the easiest way to implement this, but it won't scale well to large datasets.

Basically write a function that takes an array of options, chops one off an calls itself.