# PHP permutation multiple same elements

Tags: php, permutation

I need a function which returns all possible combinations,

e.g.

chars = range('a', 'c');

1. = a a a
2. = a a b
3. = a b a
4. = a b b
5. = a b c
6. = a c b
   ...
   n. = c c c

(order doesn't matter)

and so on

i got this

```
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) {
        $return = array($perms);
    }  else {
        $return = array();
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
         list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             $return = array_merge($return, pc_permute($newitems, $newperms));
         }
    }
    return $return;
}

$p = pc_permute(array(0, 1, 2, 3));
var_dump($p);
```

from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)

But i wasn't able to figure out how to chance/rewrite this to get all possible combination with multiple same elements.

Thanks, Mohammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this function:

```
<?php 
$characters = range('a','c');


function get_permutations(array $arr = array()){
    if(count($arr) == 1){
        return array_values($arr);
    }

    $return_array = array();

    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        $temp_arr = $arr;
        unset($temp_arr[$key]);
        $temp = call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $temp_arr);
        for($x = 0; $x < count($temp); $x++){
            $temp[$x] = $val.$temp[$x];
        }
        $return_array = array_merge($return_array, $temp);
    }
    return $return_array;
}

var_dump(get_permutations($characters));
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "acb"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bac"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "bca"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "cab"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "cba"
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php 
$characters = range('a','h');


function get_permutations(array $arr = array(), $max_length = NULL){
    if(count($arr) == 1 || ($max_length !== NULL && $max_length <= 1)){
        return array_values($arr);
    }

    $return_array = array();

    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        $temp_arr = $arr;
        unset($temp_arr[$key]);
        $temp = call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $temp_arr, $max_length !== NULL ? $max_length - 1 : NULL);
        for($x = 0; $x < count($temp); $x++){
            $temp[$x] = $val.$temp[$x];
        }
        $return_array = array_merge($return_array, $temp);
    }
    return $return_array;
}

var_dump(get_permutations($characters, 4));
```

**NOTE:** Beware using `a-z` range will lead to a greater runtime or even leads to out of memory error so i tested it with a small range :)

Comment: Thanks, works aboslutly perfect!! How could I modify this function to get range('a','z'); but with a predefined string-length, e.g. 5chars?

Comment: @Mohammer : sorry for l8 response, pass another variable and set the value and test the value to be zero and on each recursion decrease the value, check the edits in some time