# PHP List all possible 6-digit numbers with specific digits

Tags: php, loops, recursion, permutation, combinations

How could I generate every possible number of a given amount of digits and using specific digits?

So basically, I would like to have a 6 digit number for example using only the numbers ['1','2','3']. I've tried a few methods of recursion, however, I can't get it to work correctly due to my other complication, which is adding a separator of "|" in between each 2 digits. So the list would be like so:

```
11|11|11
11|11|12
11|11|13
11|11|21
11|11|22
11|11|23
```

etc..
Would be appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.
Also a way of dumping each of the combinations into my MySQL database would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers

Comment: forget the separators you can always add them later. just select a random number (between 1 and 3) 6 times and concantenate it together. check your database table to see if it exists, if not add it. run it a bunch of times. eventually you will get them all.

Comment: Also that pipe separator is just symbolic, it has no importance for the permutations algorithm so do not consider it a `complexity`

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, I can't do what I require with them, I've looked through a few questions and still can't manage to get it right. Also, I may need to expand it to around 10 digits between the separators, so I can't just do that + the fact I don't think that would order them properly.

Comment: you can always order them once they are in the database...

Comment: There's only 729 of them. Here. http://pastebin.com/7Vq3qaaU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much updated answer (originally updated from this answer][1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php)) to your question:

```
function findPermutations($arr, $arrLen, $size, $perArr = array(), $pos = 0, &$found = array()) {
   if ($size==$pos) { //if $pos reach $size then we have found one permutation
      $found[] = vsprintf("%s%s|%s%s|%s%s", $perArr);
      return;
   }
   for ($i=0; $i<$arrLen; $i++) {

      $perArr[$pos] = $arr[$i]; //put i'th char in current position
      //The recursive call that move to next position with $pos+1
      findPermutations($arr, $arrLen, $size, $perArr, $pos+1, $found); 
   }
   return $found;
}

$permutations = array();
$letters = array('1','2','3');
$max_length = 6;

$permutations = findPermutations($letters, count($letters), $max_length);

for($i = 0; $i < count($permutations); $i++) {
    print ($permutations[$i].'<br/>');
}
```

Here is what I'm doing.  I'm passing in an empty array called `$permutations` by reference, and as I find new permutations, I'm appending them to it.  When the function `findPermutations()` is complete, I end up with an array of all permutation, that I can iterate over or insert.  To get the formatting I'm using [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), that lets me pass an array of data and apply a format (in this case `%s%s|%s%s|%s%s`).  Lastly I'm using default argument values to make calling this function cleaner.

Comment: You can test this here: http://phpcodepad.com/

Comment: Thanks for that, it's perfect. However - how can I separate each 2 digits with a "|", please? Sorry, I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Thous lines above the `return` statement are for printing out each permutation, you can change them to something like `print $perArr[0].$perArr[1].'|'.$perArr[2].$perArr[3].'|'.$perArr[4].$perArr[5]` or that could eb where you add your MySQL INSERT command (I'd rename it storePermutation if you did that)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it's perfect, except I've just added them spacers and it prints the same set around 10 times before the next one? 11-11-11 is printed 10 times before 11-11-12 is..

Comment: @AqworldsDragon, Ok I've radically updated the answer to actually spit out data that you can insert or in this case print.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's actually perfect! Now I just need a server to run my script on for the bigger ones haha

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
$letters='123'; // add other numbers

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) { //generate 3 pairs
  $pairs[]=$letters[rand(0,2)] . $letters[rand(0,2)];
}
//then join them together
$finalstring=implode('-',$pairs);
```