# How to find the minimal sum of numbers drawn from multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, sum, minimum

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about solving the following problem.
I was writing this in PHP but it is more of a general programming problem and I guess it involves search algorithms and combinatorics.

Given an array containing multiple arrays/sets of numbers

```
$a[0] = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$a[1] = array(1,3,5,7,9);
$a[2] = array(2,4,6,8,10);
```

I would like to draw a number from each array such that the sum of the drawn numbers is the smallest possible. 
Also the number must be drawn from a unique array index, so in this example you couldn't draw 1, 1, 2. 
The smallest possible number sequence from the arrays above would be 3, 1, 4 which would give a sum of 8.

Now assume an input array of `n` arrays/sets containing each `m` numbers, what would be the most logical and efficient way to find the optimal sequence of numbers?

Comment: looks like a homework for you !!!

Comment: It's not homework, I encountered the problem in creating an application. My solution consisted of `n` for loops nested in each other along with a variable to keep track of the minimal sum. It did work but turned out to be very ugly code, so I was just wondering what the right approach would be here. My guess is that it would best be solved recursively, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask for input from other programmers.

Comment: Use the min() function. Then remove anything lower than current result from next array. Repeat for next array. Not really a recursive problem as your arrays arent recursive.

Comment: ToBe, I don't think that would work. If I would start with the first array (in the example) and use the min() function it would return 1, and for the next arrays it would return 3 and 6. The sum of those values would be 10 which isn't minimal in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all arrays are sorted, we can ignore the elements at indexes >= n (so we can focus on the square matrix n * n)
We generate all permutations recursively as in [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers) and for each permutation we count the sum. Though it is not optimal, but it is better than `n` nested for loops:

```
$minSum = PHP_INT_MAX;

$a[0] = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$a[1] = array(1,3,5,7,9);
$a[2] = array(2,4,6,8,10);

function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    global $a, $minSum;
    if (empty($items)) {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($perms as $i => $p) {
          $sum += $a[$i][$p];
        }
        if($sum<$minSum) {
          $minSum = $sum;
        }
    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}

pc_permute(range(0,count($a)-1));

echo "$minSum\n";
```

Comment: Using a function to generate the permutations of the indices and then calculating the sum for each of those seems like a very good approach. I didn't think of it myself in time, thank you!