# permutation combination of n variables

Tags: php, switch-statement, cartesian-product

I am going through a situation where I need to find possible combinations of getting empty values within a given four variables.

let me explain:

$one; $two; $three; $four;

And I may get null values for any of these variables, And need to perform special action on each case.

I am trying it in PHP.

Ie,

```
if(($one == '') && ($two == '') && ($three == '') && ($four == '')) {
   //some action
} 
else if (($one == '') && ($two != '') && ($three == '') && ($four == '')) {
  // some action
} else if (($one != '') && ($two == '') && ($three == '') && ($four != '')) {
  // some action
}
```

.
.
.

I tried to use permutation formula, but could not complete it.
So I will have 24 combinations. Can anyone give me a simplified solution for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language? Please add a tag.

Comment: Where do you get 24 combinations? With 4 different variables, each either null or not, you have 16 different combinations. And as @jotik asks, what's the language you're using?

Comment: I am trying this in PHP, And the chances of combination is 4*3*2*1

Comment: Am i right you want to react different in all those situations?

Comment: I need to know the background of this problem, in order to give you a more useful answer.

Comment: I tried with this code, but I could not convert it for my need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers

And in my case i have four different prices, 
variable one = $20; variable $two = $40

And suppose if one and two are not empty,
i need to set price as ($20 + $40)

Comment: If you only care about each value null or not, then number of choices = 2*2*2*2 = 16

Comment: Yes, you are right, its combination of 16.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the redundancy of checking the nulls by doing something like this:

```
$n = ($one == '' ? 0 : 1) + ($two == '' ? 0 : 2) + ($three == '' ? 0 : 4) + ($four == '' ? 0 : 8)
```

Then use a switch statement to check the value of `$n` which will be between `0` and `15` for the 16 different combinations.

```
switch ($n) {
    case 0:
        // case where all four values are ''
        break;
    case 1:
        // case where just $one is not ''
        break;
    case 2:
        // case where just $two is not ''
        break;
    case 3:
        // case where $one and $two are not '' but $three and $four are ''
        break;

    ...

    case 15:
        // case where all four values are not ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused on the combinatorics here.

If you were only checking **whether some fixed number *n* of the strings were empty**, regardless of which ones, that would be a combination, and there would be C(4,*n*) cases of interest.

If you were interested in **which ones were empty, but only if exactly *n* of them were empty**, that would be a permutation, and there would be P(4,*n*) cases of interest.

But it seems like you are interested in **which ones are empty, regardless of how many**. That is a Cartesian product, and you need 2^4=16 cases.

When you want to enumerate something like this, think of it like counting up on a four-digit binary number, where each digit represents one of the variables (in order) and 1 indicates that it is not empty:

- 0000
- 0001
- 0010
- 0011
- 0100
- etc.

So the brute-force linear search on these possibilities would be something like

```
//0000
if (($one == '') && ($two == '') && ($three == '') && ($four == '')) {
   //some action
} 
//0001
else if (($one == '') && ($two == '') && ($three == '') && ($four != '')) {
  // some action
}
//0010
else if (($one == '') && ($two == '') && ($three != '') && ($four == '')) {
  // some action
}
//0011
else if (($one == '') && ($two == '') && ($three != '') && ($four != '')) {
  // some action
}
...
```

However, since you're essentially looking at a series of Boolean decisions, I would suggest a binary search tree. It will be somewhat less handsome code, but it is the most efficient way to search something like this (it will take log_2(16)=4 `if` statements, rather than 16 -- and no logical && to process).

```
//Is $one empty?
if ($one == '') {

    //Yes, $one is empty. Is $two empty?
    if ($two == '') {

        //Yes, $two is empty. Is $three empty?
        if ($three == '') {

            //Yes, $three is empty. Is $four empty?
            if ($four == '') {
                //Yes, $four is empty. The case is 0000
            } else {
                //No, $four is not empty. The case is 0001
            }

        } else {

            //No, $three is not empty. Is $four empty?
            if ($four == '') {
                //Yes, $four is empty. The case is 0010
            } else {
                //No, $four is not empty. The case is 0011
            }
        }
    } else

        //No, $two is not empty. Is $three empty?
        if ($three == '') {
        ...
```

Now, this code is very efficient, but it is also very verbose. If any of these cases will behave in the same way, I would suggest trying to find some other logical hierarchy that will decide on distinct behaviors in as few steps as possible -- but in any case I do suggest a logical *hierarchy* rather than the linear enumeration you're attempting. Best of luck!

**EDIT:**
Lurker's suggestion of

```
$n = ($one == '' ? 0 : 1) + ($two == '' ? 0 : 2) + ($three == '' ? 0 : 4) + ($four == '' ? 0 : 8)
```

followed by a `switch` statement is a much, much cleaner solution than mine above. I want to point out that the underlying logic is exactly the same; this line of code is in fact building the binary number I described above, but in base 10. Hopefully you can see the correspondence between my answer and Lurker's, and hopefully my answer will help you understand why Lurker's superior code works.