# How to permute numbers without duplicates with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, combinations, permutation

i need to make numbers permutations (with some features), but
my .php and mysql is not so improved.
The numbers will be posted by a .html form, max 10 numbers.
It will permute the numbers to create unique thousand number:

if 4 different numbers is posted by the .html input (1,2,3,4):
will return: 1234,1243,1324,1342... (24 unique combinations)

if 5 different numbers is posted by the .html input (1,2,3,4,5):
will return: 1234,1235,1243,... (120 unique combinations)

The number will only repeat if it posted, as (1,1,2,4)
will return: 1124, 1142, 1214,...(12 unique combinations)

Then i need to store the combinations into a mysql row, comma separated.

I tryed this function(found here [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)):

```
$p = permutate(array('1','2','3'));
foreach($p as $perm)
print join("",$perm)."|\n";
function permutate($elements, $perm = array(), &$permArray = array())
{
if(empty($elements))
{
   array_push($permArray,$perm); return;
}

for($i=0;$i<=count($elements)-1;$i++)
{
   array_push($perm,$elements[$i]);
   $tmp = $elements; array_splice($tmp,$i,1);
   permutate($tmp,$perm,$permArray);
   array_pop($perm);
}

return $permArray;
}
```

The output: 123| 132| 213| 231| 312| 321|

But when is given:
    $p = permutate(array('1','2','2'));

the output is: 122| 122| 212| 221| 212| 221|
When should be 122|212|221

I tried array_unique, but did´t work, probally becouse i did it wrong.

Thx

Comment: *I tried array_unique* -- show how.

Comment: here array_unique($perm);

Comment: Do you know that array_unique do not updates variable and returns new value?

Comment: Try it one more time

Answer (score 0):

First convert each result to string and then de-dupe the array:

```
$p = permutate(array('1','2','3'));
$result = array();
foreach($p as $perm) {
   $result[]=join("",$perm);
}
$result = array_unique($result);
print join("|", $result);
```

Comment: I've edited my answer - I forgot to print out the result. Now you can replace the first three lines with my code.