# lazy string comparison in PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison, ocr

I have the following task:

string A: well known, can contains `0`, `O`, `i`, `I`, `1` for sure - lets say a kind of article number.

string B: a string coming from an OCR. So some of the "`0`"s can here also be a "`O`", some "`1`"s can be a "`l`". The string has length of about 300 (just to get a feeling)

Now, I would like to know, if the OCR text contains my article number. So in princible, I have to check the OCR as it is at first. When not found, I will replace a first "`O`" by a "`0`" and try again. Now I have to try all combinations.

My idea was to define some arrays containing which letter can have similar letters:

```
[
    ["i", "l", "j", "1"], 
    ["0", "o"], 
    [".", "*"]
]
```

To reduce the array size (and therefore the amount of possible combinations) I will put everything in lower case.

Now, the hard work starts. Do you know a smart way to walk through the combinations?

Thank you very much in advanced for your help!

Comment: This may point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers - it becomes more complex as you'd have the number of permutations changes depending on the number of "lazy" matches\

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpfull link! Yes, it seems, it gets very time consuming, having 10x "i"-like and 10x "0"-like letters. It results in several million possibilities. Perhaps I have to transfer all "i"-like-letters to "i"s and so on and compare them. There are some risks to compare wrong strings, but much faster than my first idea :-(